# fglrx works on Ubuntu 12.10 (32-bit), but not Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit) on the same computer. How do I fix it on the 64-bit install?

Tags: unity, 12.10, 64-bit, fglrx, 32-bit

I have followed instructions for every option listed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) (uninstalling in between attempts, of course), but each one results in Unity not loading; no sidebar, no desktop icons, and no window borders.  Moreover, it's incredibly buggy, with programs like Firefox often crashing after a few moments of use.

Here's a list of some things I think may be relevant:

- `lsmod | grep fglrx` and `lsmod | grep radeon` give no output.
- `fglrxinfo` results in a BadRequest error.  `amdcccle` runs, but also generates a flood of BadRequest errors in the terminal.
- `lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A3` indicates that the system is using radeon instead of fglrx, and fglrx is not even listed as a usable kernel module.
- My /etc/X11/xorg.conf file is [here.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5612549)
- `modprobe fglrx` returns `FATAL: Module fglrx not found.` but `sudo apt-get install fglrx` informs me that I have the latest version of fglrx installed.
- fglrx ran fine on Ubuntu 12.10 (32-bit), but installing Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit) clean and then immediately installing fglrx results in the problems I am experiencing.
- I am using a Radeon HD 7770.

Some have told me to simply uninstall fglrx and use Ubuntu that way, but Ubuntu is...quite unusable without it.  I get about 5 FPS average (with a 7770!) using the default drivers, and compiz runs at 100% CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  Log in, and when Unity refuses to load, follow these steps:

1. Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open up the terminal.
2. Run `sudo apt-get update`, type your password, then hit enter.
3. Run `sudo apt-get upgrade`
4. Install any packages that report that they weren't installed.  You can do this by running `sudo apt-get install PACKAGENAME`
5. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until no packages are installed by step 3 and no packages report that they weren't installed.
6. Run `sudo reboot`

And you're done!  fglrx should work as intended.